# Magento 2.3 - How to modify language pack

Tags: magento2, localisation, language-package

I have a language pack that I cloned from git into my project.
The path to the module is: `app/i18n/magenerds/de_DE`
It's `registration.php`says

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
    'magenerds_de_de',
    __DIR__
);
```

Now I need to add a translation that doesn't seem to be included in that language pack:
The title of the category navigation on the left in the category view is still in english, it says "Categories"
Here's what I did:

1. Created a new folder: `app/i18n/myproject/de_DE`
2. added a `registration.php`
3. added a `language.xml`
4. added a `de_DE.csv`
5. `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
6. `bin/magento cache:flush`

Magento is set to default mode so no need to deploy static content, correct?
I flushed everything in the cache section in the backend though to be sure.

This is what's in the files:

> language.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd">
  <code>de_DE</code>
  <vendor>myproject</vendor>
  <package>de_de</package>
  <sort_order>10</sort_order>
  <use vendor="magenerds" package="de_de" />
</language>
```

> registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
'myproject_de_de',
__DIR__
);
```

> de_DE.csv

```
"Categories","Kategorien"
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.
What did I miss?

Comment: Check if the vendor node in app/i18n/magenerds/de_DE/language.xml is 'magenerds' if no modify your use.

If you are not in developer mode, don't forget to 'bin/magento static-content:deploy'

Comment: @Chaz did you find any way ?